# What could be the name of this rare type of HP Pavilion power connectors?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power, hp-pavilion

It is a HP Pavilion G6 laptop, and I am trying to identify its uncommon power plug. Looking around on the net, I see only the more standard, center pin power plugs, but not this. I think, maybe *most* HP pavilion G6 might have the common center-pin power socket, but this is an exception.

On this image, we can see in the middle a 5-pin power connector. Around a central pin, we can see 4 other pins in a *symmetrical*, *rectangular* layout.

What is its name?

Additionally, I see the following data on the plate, below the battery:

- Serial: 5CD2076JFW
- Product: B1Y27EA#BH4
- Model: g6 - 1308sk

[image]

Comment: @K7AAY Thanks, I did. It wasn't on the bottom, it was below the battery, but finally I've found. I extended it into the post.

Comment: I don't sell, I volunteer to help here. It is a center pin or 'coaxial' connector, made by Philmore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Service Guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03094322) on pages 18 and 21 shows the replacement female coaxial power connector with cord which fits inside the laptop is HP Part # 641137-001. The 90W power supply is [commonly available](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS804US804&q=g6-1308sk+power+supply) on [Amazon in Germany](https://www.amazon.de/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Netzteil%20HP%20Pavilion%20G6%2090W&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3ANetzteil%20HP%20Pavilion%20G6%2090W). Page 29 of the Service Guide shows the part numbers for the power supply (609947-001) and power cords (in your case, 490371-021).  If you can't find the power plug from the information which follows, then get a replacement power supply, which Stateside is only $9-$25.

That male coaxial power plug is sold by [Frys.com](https://www.frys.com/product/7310264) [image: Philmore DC plug].

and is described as "Commonly used on power supplies for many Dell and HP laptop computers, this end can be used on 2 wire or 3 wire power cords. Features Outside Diameter: 7.4mm Inside Diameter: 5.0mm Center Pin: 0.6mm Rating: 18.5-19VDC @ 4A Maximum."

Product details

Specification
SKU     7310264
Model   274
Brand   PHILMORE
UPC     038975002743

The four symmetrical, rectangular holes are an artifact of the injection molding process used to make the female connector, and have no connector behind them.

Comment: Thank you very much the extensive search! However, as you can see, it has 5 pins. The search what you suggested shows only the typical center-pin layout. I searched for the images for this serial number, but I've found nothing what would look like the father version of this connector. Although most images aren't very clear.

Comment: @peterh Why do you think that every hole must indicate a pin?

Comment: _peterh_, just take a close look at one of the plug ends on any of the https://www.google.com/search?num=100&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS804US804&q=g6-1308sk+power+supply replacements I found. You will see there's only one center pin, no four symmetrical, rectangular pins surrounding it inside the outer shell.  Freund, I volunteered at http://freegeek.org refurbishing donated laptops for a couple of years, and I have seen hundreds of those power supplies on HP Pavillions.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes. It could be overridden using tor, but probably they ship anything only to an U.S. address. So I would need to utilize an U.S. friend as proxy.

Comment: @K7AAY I believe you, but I ask you to believe what is on my picture. It is a connector with 5 pins. I can imagine that not all is bound (although I think it is unlikely).

Comment: @peterh Per your picture, I believe that there are four holes surrounding the center hole. But I see no evidence that there are contacts inside those holes. If there were, then mating such a thing would risk bending those pins.

Comment: _peterh_, then search on the UPC code 038975002743 I just provided for the plug, and you will see; or, B) just order an entire replacement power supply with the part number I extracted from page 29 of the service manual. Or,C) order from Amazon.de https://www.amazon.de/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Netzteil%20HP%20Pavilion%20G6%2090W&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3ANetzteil%20HP%20Pavilion%20G6%2090W or, D)  visit your Friendly Neighborhood Computer Store, laptop in hand, and say, "I want to find a replacement power supply for this laptop."

Comment: @JamieHanrahan Thanks. This is what also I suspect, despite that it is highly uncommon. The original HP papers are too strong argument to simply deny it.

Comment: @K7AAY Well, in Germany it is not so simple, service costs are in the skies. They would likely say that my laptop doesn't worth their price and they will have right. My secondary goal is to do some old-laptop-revival hobby repair. I think your argument, citing the original HP papers are too strong, despite that it looks uncommon. So I bought a power supply (price was 18 EUR + shipping). It will be shipped between 1/4 - 1/10. +1 given. If it matches, you get an accept, too :-) Thank you very much again!